# How to create a push down of screens in React Navigation

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to push down the whole navigation screen including the header? I need to push down my screen like the following image. Not sure where to start on accomplishing this. Will I need to nest my whole navigation inside another container?

[image: Push down example]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can wrap your navigator by another component like `<View>` and style it.
Maybe it has some better solutions but wrapping is just fine and I did it before.

Comment: Do you have any examples on how you did this? I'm assuming you wrapped one of the stacks inside a view?

Answer (score 1):

there is a built-in option for that - you need to set `mode: 'modal'` to your stack navigator, eg:

```
const MainStack = initialRouteName =>
  StackNavigator(
    {
...
    },
    {
      ...navStyles,
      initialRouteName,
      mode: 'modal',
    }
  );
```

note this will only have an effect on ios, because such pattern is not present on android

Comment: I have the stack set to modal just not clear on how to push this stack down.   `const NestedHomecreens = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: Notifications,
  }
  }, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal',
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    },
})`